# Objects pass through each other

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I've two objects, one is static and another one is dynamic. Fixtures of both of them created from `ChainShape`. The problem is that they pass through each other.

Screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ChainShapes dont collide with each other make one of them a PolygonShape.
This works for me:

```
BodyDef triangleDef = new BodyDef();
triangleDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
triangleDef.position.set( 0, 0 );
Body triangleBody = this.world.createBody( triangleDef );
PolygonShape triangleShape = new PolygonShape();
triangleShape.set( new float[]{ 0, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f } );
triangleBody.createFixture( triangleShape, 1 );
triangleShape.dispose();

BodyDef groundDef = new BodyDef();
triangleDef.position.set( 0, 0 );
Body groundBody = this.world.createBody( groundDef );
ChainShape groundShape = new ChainShape();
groundShape.createLoop( new float[]{ -10, 10, -10, -10, 10, -10, 10, 10 } );
groundBody.createFixture( groundShape, 1 );
groundShape.dispose();
```

Comment: Both of the bodies will have more than 8 vertices, so i just cant use polygon shape. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You could split the shape into several polygonshapes and add them all to the same body.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answers